# What effect does amplitude have on EM waves?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

There have been previous questions like this regarding light/photons specifically. My question is what the effect of the amplitude is on, say, a gamma wave? It would change its energy, as $E = h f$. Maybe amplitude doesn't even exist with an EM wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electric and magnetic field strength ($\bf{E}$ and $\bf{B}$)
is a concept of *classical* electrodynamics.
It emerges from *quantum* electrodynamics
as a collective effect only when there are *many* photons.

When considering only a few photons or even a single photon
(like when you have gamma rays) it doesn't make sense
to talk about electric and magnetic field or their amplitude.

The energy of a single photon is $E=hf$ (where $f$
is the frequency of the EM wave).
Therefore, the amplitude of electric and magnetic field
has no effect on the energy of the single photons.
Instead, the amplitude effects the *number* of photons.

The energy density of the EM field (i.e. energy per volume) is
$$\rho=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\bf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\bf{B}^2.$$
Therefore in an EM wave the number $N$ of photons within a volume
can be calculated from the volume integral
$$\begin{align}
N hf &= \int_V \rho\ dV \\
 &= \int_V \left( \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\bf{E}^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\bf{B}^2 \right)dV \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\hat{\bf{E}}^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\hat{\bf{B}}^2 \right) V
\end{align}$$
where $\hat{\bf{E}}$ and $\hat{\bf{B}}$ are the amplitudes of the EM wave.

Comment: If the amplitude is the number of photons, then I take it it's the RMS value, since I don't think the number of photons would go to 0 and into the negative temporarily.

Comment: More precisely: the squared amplitude multiplied by volume.
See my updated answer.